# Matlab linking a function in a "for-end" from a script

Tags: matlab

I have this script:
tema2.m

```
n=input ('Numarul de sfere :');
for i= 1:n
str= ['Introduceti raza sferei  ',num2str(i), ' : '];
r=input(str)
[v a]= sfera(r);
run ('sfera.m')
end
```

and this function:
sfera.m

```
function [v a]=sfera(r)
    % SFERA (raza)
    % calculeaza volumul si aria unei sfere
     %VOLUMUL (raza)
    % calculeaza volumul unei sfere
    v= @(r) 4/3 * pi * r^3 ;
    v= v(r)
    %ARIE (raza)
    %calculeaza aria unei sfere
    a= @(r) 4* pi * r^2 ;
    a= a(r)
end
```

I need to calculate the volume and the surface of a sphere, using a script in which I give the data's for n spheres.

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to get that code working, I've edited it so that it will run.

script.m

```
n=input ('Numarul de sfere :');
for i= 1:n
    str= ['Introduceti raza sferei  ',num2str(i), ' : '];
    r=input(str);
    [v a]= sfera(r);
end
```

sfera.m

```
function [v a]=sfera(r)
    % SFERA (raza)
    % calculeaza volumul si aria unei sfere
     %VOLUMUL (raza)
    % calculeaza volumul unei sfere
    v= 4/3 * pi * r^3 ;
    %ARIE (raza)
    %calculeaza aria unei sfere
    a= 4* pi * r^2 ;
end
```